# Acceder a dominio:puerto usando nginx

Tags: nginx

Tengo una configuración nginx que me funciona correctamente y que me está apuntando mediante proxy_pass a un puerto en mi localhost. Sin embargo, me gustaría poder acceder a otros puertos de mi localhost, usando el mismo dominio pero apuntando a otros puertos, por ejemplo:

Acceder a **dominio.com:4590** y me esté mostrando lo que tengo cargando en mi **localhost:4590** y si decido acceder a **dominio.com:4591** me muestra que hay en **localhost:4591**.

Esta es mi configuración actual, me gustaría cambiarla para conseguir lo mencionado anteriormente:

```
server {

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
                # Do not allow connections from docker 1.5 and earlier
                # docker pre-1.6.0 did not properly set the user agent on ping, catch "Go *" user agents
                if ($http_user_agent ~ "^(docker\/1\.(3|4|5(?!\.[0-9]-dev))|Go ).*$" ) {
                        return 404;
                }

                proxy_pass                          localhost:4591;
                proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout                  900;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate ....; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key ....; # managed by Certbot

        include ....; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_dhparam ....; # managed by Certbot
}
```